# ipad image swapping issues

Tags: ios, ipad, safari

I've come across this really odd bug and can't seem to find any information on it anywhere.

Basically, I have lots of images on my website, as you do. There's nothing wrong with any of the code - it must be the iPad I'm using as PC in all browsers + my iPhone work fine.

Basically, it seems to favour one particular image on the page, and replaces other images with this image?! So I get the same image in lots of different places on screen, where there should be lots of different images... if that makes sense.

Has anyone else come across this problem and have any ideas of how to fix?

Many thanks

Edit: Could be worth pointing out that I'm using a 3G connection, although it seems to work fien on my iPhone with 3G - and it can't be caching issues as I've cleared many times and every image has always had a different name...

Comment: This might be related to the Image swapping issue on iOS for ipad and iphone. It seems that this has been around since version 5, and still present in version 9. A thread from [discusssions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6574663?start=0&tstart=0). Leaving this as a note in case others pass by here looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried viewing your website on Safari?
And also on other browsers (FireFox/Chrome etc)